# Django editable dropdown field

Tags: python, django, django-models

In the admin interface, I have an affiliation associated with each user. Obviously, I want to be able to edit this affiliation at any time. Different users will often have the same affiliation, but not necessarily.

Currently, I am using a `TextField`, however, I want to be able to click on the users affiliation and edit it, and as I am editing it, I want to see other affiliations that are being used by other users. That way, if I want the user I am editing to have the same affiliation as an already existing user, I will easily know of that existing affiliation.

Is there an existing Django field that acts like this? Or can I modify an existing field to act do this?

This is essentially what I want (at least the left portion of the image):

[image: Editable dropdown I want to add to admin interface]

Please let me know if you need any clarification.

Comment: So you want this text field to act like an auto-complete..?