# Add editable choices in django

Tags: python, django, autocomplete

I am trying to add a editable choicefield in django like the picture, already do some research on this. Unfortunately, the solution like django-autocomplete doesn't quite fulfill my needs. The autocomplete looks fine, but if do so, I need create a django modal to generate the choices through a url view request, but in my case, it doesn't necessary to do that, I just need put these 3 choices for ip address in the dropdown list, and choose one of them then edit it or submit.

The solutions I found, but they are not very well fit my need:

[Django admin: Change selected box of related fields to autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9793707/django-admin-change-selected-box-of-related-fields-to-autocomplete)

[Django editable dropdown field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22540271/django-editable-drohttps://stackedit.io/editor#pdown-field)

[image]

Comment: I found using jquery-ui autocomplete and an ajax call to get the options (or if you want static options, can just put them directly in the autocomplete javascript code) was the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use *just* those three entries the quickest way is to use a `datalist`, it just needs to be added into your HTML somewhere.

```html
<div id="page-wrapper">
    <label for="ip">Network address</label>
    <input type="text" id="ip" list="ip-datalist">
    <datalist id="ip-datalist">
      <option>192.168.0.0/24</option>
      <option>10.0.0.0/24</option>
      <option>172.16.0.0/24</option>
    </datalist>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your options are likely to never change, you could hardcode them into your html like the answer above. If you're generating your dropdown using a form however it would be better to do something like this:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):

    ip_list = ((1, '192.168.0.0/24'), (2, '10.0.0.0/24'),
        (3, '172.16.0.0/24'), )

    network_address = forms.ChoiceField(label='Network Address',
        choices=ip_list)
    ...
```

Once you render the form object in your template it ends up producing html like this:

```
<label for="id_network_address">Network Address:</label>
<select id="id_network_address" name="network_address">
    <option value="1">192.168.0.0/24</option>
    <option value="2">10.0.0.0/24</option>
    <option value="3">172.16.0.0/24</option>
</select>
```

This way it is easier to change the `ip_list` in future if you need to, plus its keeps all your code in one place. This is explained in the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield).